# Gulp.js error when executing a "build" task

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I'm using gulp to facilitate a typescript build system. This is for an Angular 2 frontend.

The issue I am running into is with my "build" task that I have setup.
Here is the task in question

```
gulp.task('build', ['compile', 'copy:js','copy:html', 'copy:css', 'copy:systemjs']);
```

The individual tasks that the the "build" task ends up calling mainly move files to a dist folder. The compile task is what actually ends up calling tsc to transpile the typescript to the dist folder.

Here is the output from the "build" task

```
C:\<project directory>\node_modules\.bin\gulp build
gulp[36580]: src\node_contextify.cc:629: Assertion 'args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: 00007FF6DE1E6AE5
 2: 00007FF6DE1C2756
 3: 00007FF6DE1C2821
 4: 00007FF6DE19A5AA
 5: 00007FF6DE7E4002
 6: 00007FF6DE7E5158
 7: 00007FF6DE7E44BD
 8: 00007FF6DE7E43DB
 9: 0000017B1E1041C1
```

I'm not sure where exactly this error is getting thrown from, and I'm not sure if it is something related to the gulp tasks themselves.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is that a backtick ` at the beginning of args[1]?  And a regular single quote at the end?  Is that intended?

Comment: Hi @Mark, I just fixed that. It wasn't intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I have figured out the issue here.

The version of gulp I was using, 3.9.1, doesn't support node 10.6.0. So, I switched back to the current LTS version of node (8.11.3). Now my build system is working fine.

So, all in all, make sure to check for version incompatibilities with the packages you are using.

Comment: Please, how did you discover / where did you find that Gulp 3.9.x didn't support Node 10.6? Your q/a was the first answer I found related to my (similar) problem though I use node 10.3 and npm 6.4.1 but apart from [`"node": ">= 0.10"`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/package.json#L14) I can't find anything related :/